# Cloudsearch Date range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have cloudsearch documents in the following format and I am using simple queryParser. So, when I search for 'abc', I get two results since two documents contain firstname as "abc". How can I take it to the next level and add a date range to the query? Something like, I want to search for "abc" between two dates where started >= date1 and started < date2. One approach I can think of is before uploading the documents, convert the started field to timeinMillis and then do a range. Is that the only way to approach this or can I build a range for dates too?

```
  {
    "id": "d48810e8-082a-4422-887c-a3a69aa95f3e",
    "fields": {
      "origin": [
        "http://localhost:3006"
      ],
      "firstname": [
        "abc"
      ],
      "started": [
        "2017-03-30T15:45:03.848Z"
      ],
      "lastname": [
        "xyz"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "47ae007e-41ec-4110-82f1-716d4e48670c",
    "fields": {
      "origin": [
        "http://localhost:3006"
      ],
      "firstname": [
        "opq"
      ],
      "lastname": [
        "rst"
      ],
      "started": [
        "2017-01-09T20:00:47.264Z"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "6a6df5be-9518-44f4-8b9d-62ff21c5e89c",
    "fields": {
      "origin": [
        "http://localhost:3006"
      ],
      "firstname": [
        "abc"
      ],
      "lastname": [
        "xyz"
      ],
      "started": [
        "2017-01-18T19:09:01.318Z"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudSearch supports a `date` field type ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-index-fields.html)). Use that and all your concerns around converting to millis go away.

To search for a date range, use the `range` syntax ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-ranges.html)), eg 
`started:['2013-01-01T00:00:00Z',}` to search for entries with a `started` after that date

Combine that with your text query using boolean operators, eg `(AND firstname :'abc' started:['2013-01-01T00:00:00Z',})` and make sure to use the structured query parser

Comment: Thanks @alexroussos for the response. The only problem with that is, I want to search for 'abc' in any field in the document, not just firstname. Since I'm using simple query parser now, my cloudsearch returns all the documents that contains 'abc' in any value.

Comment: Then don't specify the field. From the docs on `q.options`: _If no fields are specified in a search and this option is not specified, all statically configured text and text-array fields are searched._ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/search-api.html